# CORS allowed when no response header Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cors, cross-domain

I'm able to send post/put/delete to my localhost even though the response headers doesn't include "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" , I'm using chrome so my question:

1- will requests from different site allowed if no "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" returned ?

2- why the request worked on my local host , the browser sent the following headers in request :

Origin: http://localhost:8080

or the browsers ignore the response header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" when it's the same origin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will requests from different site allowed if no "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" returned ?

A POST request, all else being equal, will be allowed, but the Same Origin Policy will prevent JS from reading the response.

PUT and DELETE requests require a Preflight request to receive permission from CORS first, so the requests will be blocked.

> why the request worked on my local host

The Same Origin Policy doesn't block access when the  request is from the same origin.

Comment: so the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  is never needed on same origin even if Origin header is sent by the browser right ?